# PHP - Converting Excel to PDF (Phpspreadsheet) - Operation not permitted

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to convert an Excel file to PDF (Base64).

This is the code that converts the Excel to PDF:

```
$spreadsheet = $this->objPHPExcel = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("MyExcelFile.xlsx");

$class = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf::class;
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::registerWriter('Pdf', $class);
$this->objPHPExcel = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Pdf');
$this->objPHPExcel->writeAllSheets();

//Save the file. (THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCUR)   
$this->objPHPExcel->save(storage_path() . '/app/temp_files/' . $newFileName);
```

**Everything works locally, but whenever I try to run the same code on my Laravel Forge server, I get below error:**

```
unlink(/tmp/imagick-3.4.0.tgz): Operation not permitted
```

If I trace the error, it is in this specific line:

```
$this->objPHPExcel->save(storage_path() . '/app/temp_files/' . $newFileName);
```

As said, this code runs fine locally. The temp file `$newFileName` is created inside my `/temp_files` folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the solution to this was rather tricky. I found out that it had nothing to do with `Phpspreadsheet` but rather `Mpdf`.

The problem was that the file "imagick-3.4.0.tgz" file permission was set to read only. Mening that `unlink` could not work on this specific file. This goes all the way back to when I first installed the `imagick` library.

The solution was to go to the `/tmp` folder and delete the `imagick-3.4.0.tgz` file manually. This folder should actually be deleted when doing the `imagick` installation.